# 定数の読み込みについて

Tags: php

サイト毎に異なる設定値を定数で定義しているのですが、期待した通り読み込めません。
変数は読み込めます。
foreachの中で、それぞれの定数を読み込むにはどうすれば良いですか？

a/config.php

```
define('COUNTRY','日本');
$area = '日本';
```

b/config.php

```
define('COUNTRY','アメリカ');
$area = 'アメリカ';
```

index.php

```
$ary = ['/var/www/hoge/a','/var/www/hoge/b'];
foreach ($ary as $path) {
  include( $path."/config.php");
  echo COUNTRY; //期待通り出力されない。日本　日本
  echo $area; //期待通り出力される。日本　アメリカ
}
```

Comment: PHPのエラーやワーニングは発生していませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

defineで定義したものは二重に定義できません。先に定義したものが残ります。
再定義するのであれば、[runkit_constant_redefine](https://php.nicedoc.net/function.runkit-constant-redefine.html)　を使う必要があります。

a/config.php

```
if (!defined('COUNTRY')) {
    define('COUNTRY', '日本');
} else {
    runkit_constant_redefine('COUNTRY', '日本');
}
$area = '日本';
```

Comment: 二重定義になるのですね。foreach 内なのでループする度に新たに定義することになるのかと思っていました…